# Does many-to-one reduction imply polynomial time reduction?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, turing-machines

We know that if $A \le_p B$, then $A$ can be reduced to $B$ in polynomial time. And we also know that if $A \le_m B$, then $A$ is many-to-one reduction to $B$.

Can we deduce that if $A \le_m B$ then $A \le_p B$?

Comment: Turing reducibility is at least weaker than Karp reducibility, by that I mean that if $A\leq_p B$ then $A\leq_m B$. It is not known if the converse is true, however.

Comment: @FPE $\leq_m$ is not Turing reduction. It is called the "many-to-one reduction". Moreover, in the first sentence, it unclear what kind of reduction is meant in the quote "then A can be reduced to B in polynomial time". Is this this suppose to be a polynomial time many-to-one reduction or a polynomial time Turing reduction, i.e. a Karp or Cook reduction?

Comment: @William: From my comment, you can gather that I know what a Turing reduction is and what a Karp reduction is. I understood the OP as he was defining $\leq_m$ as Turing reduction and $\leq_p$ as Karp reductions.

Comment: @FPE The standard notion for Turing reduction is $\leq_T$ and the standard meaning of $\leq_m$ is many-to-one reduction? From the OP's many posts over the last several weeks under several since deleted accounts, $\leq_m$ means many-to-one reduction if there is any consistency at all to be expected from this user.

Comment: @Davied Zuhraph: please follow the advice that has been given about how to write better questions. The three questions that you asked today don't meet the expectations for this site; that is why they end up being placed on hold. There is additional information at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @William: I know what the standard notation is, but it remains a notation. From an inexperienced person, one can expect sometimes a misuse of notation, and I thought that the OP was *defining* his notations in the first two sentences, not stating properties. Well, we agree on the "mathematical" side, so there is no real problem here.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: Is your question "Does many-one reducibility (with no restriction on the time required to reduce) implies polynomial-time many-one reducibility?"

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: no, the language QBF (which is PSPACE complete) is many-one reducible to, say, $(s,t)$-PATH (which is in NL), but this reduction can't be polynomial time (since NL$\neq$ PSPACE).

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: Please see if my answer suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the question is: "Suppose that $A$ is many-one reducible to $B$. Is $A$ polytime many-one reducible to $B$?"

The answer is no.
The language $\{\Phi : \Phi\text{ valid boolean formula with quantifiers}\}$  is $\mathsf{PSPACE}$-complete (sometimes known as QBF or TQBF). One can many-one reduce this language to the language $\{(G,s,t) : G \text{ graph,} s,t\in G, \text{ there is a path from $s$ to $t$}\}$, which is in $\mathsf{NL}$ (called REACHABILITY, PATH, or the like). Given $\Phi$, the reduction tests if the formula is valid (in polynomial space). If it is, the reduction maps $\Phi$ to the edge graph $\{s,t\}$. Otherwise, the reduction maps $\Phi$ to the graph on 2 vertices $\{s,t\}$ with no edges.

However, no many-one reduction can be done in polynomial time, as per the Space hierarchy theorem, which entails that $\mathsf{NL}\subsetneq \mathsf{PSPACE}$.

Comment: I thought that the question was whether many-one reducibility implies polynomial-time many-one reducibility. (Of course it doesn't.)

Comment: @Carl Mummert: my bad, reading the question again under this light makes perfect sense.

Comment: An alternative: If you just take an infinite set $A$ that is computable. but not in polynomial time, and an infinite set $B$ that is computable in polynomial time, the sets are many-one equivalent, but $A$ cannot be reduced to $B$ in polynomial time. @FPE